# How to get rid of white lines in confusion matrix?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

Does anyone know why these white lines are quartering my confusion matrix? I've changed many of the parameters but cannot figure it out. The only thing that makes them go away is if I don't label the blocks at all, ie '0', '1',... but that's  obviously not what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm,
                          target_names = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                          title = 'Confusion matrix',
                          cmap = None,
                          normalize = False):
    """
    given a sklearn confusion matrix (cm), make a nice plot

    Arguments
    ---------
    cm:           confusion matrix from sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix

    target_names: given classification classes such as [0, 1, 2]
                  the class names, for example: ['high', 'medium', 'low']

    title:        the text to display at the top of the matrix

    cmap:         the gradient of the values displayed from matplotlib.pyplot.cm
                  see http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
                  plt.get_cmap('jet') or plt.cm.Blues

    normalize:    If False, plot the raw numbers
                  If True, plot the proportions

    Usage
    -----
    plot_confusion_matrix(cm           = cm,                  # confusion matrix created by
                                                              # sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix
                          normalize    = True,                # show proportions
                          target_names = y_labels_vals,       # list of names of the classes
                          title        = best_estimator_name) # title of graph

    Citiation
    ---------
    http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html

    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import itertools

    accuracy = np.trace(cm) / float(np.sum(cm))
    misclass = 1 - accuracy

    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')

    plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()

    if target_names is not None:
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(target_names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, target_names, rotation = 0)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, target_names)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis = 1)[:, np.newaxis]


    thresh = cm.max() / 1.5 if normalize else cm.max() / 2
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        if normalize:
            plt.text(j, i, "{:0.4f}".format(cm[i, j]),
                     horizontalalignment = "center",
                     color = "white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
        else:
            plt.text(j, i, "{:,}".format(cm[i, j]),
                     horizontalalignment = "center",
                     color = "white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")


    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label\naccuracy={:0.4f}; misclass={:0.4f}'.format(accuracy, misclass))
    plt.show()


plot_confusion_matrix(cm           = (confusion), 
                      normalize    = True,
                      target_names = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                      title        = "Confusion Matrix")
```

Output is:

[image]

Comment: I suppose that you have to only disable grid

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that these white lines are grid drawn by `pyplot` by default and you have to disable it. I don't know exact function, but it should be easy to find one.

Comment: Thank you! That got me in the right direction, I didn't know what it was called.

Needed to a `plt.grid(None)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

plt.grid(False)

plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, normalize=False, title='Normalized confusion matrix')
```

Comment: try formatting your code between three backticks if you look there is a link to show you everything you can do in posts with markdown. put your code between ```code here ```

Comment: plt.grid(False) was what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting it

```
import seaborn as sns 
# Try resetting it 
sns.reset_orig()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).